# How do I password protect a page of posts on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have several pages on my site and I want to password protect a page which contains the latest posts.

Simply going to the admin panel and setting **Visibility: Password protected** isn't doing anything so.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide more info about your Wordpress?

Comment: It's a locally-hosted installation, using the Ascent theme https://wordpress.org/themes/ascent/. It's running on WordPress 4.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Check you browser console first may be some javascript file cause
   of error.
2. If the issue not resolved with this, deactivate all plugins and
       check console again. Then activate the plugins one by one
       and check which one is conflicting.
3. If the error is still there change you theme to one of default WordPress
       themes and check, has your issue been resolved.
4. If issue still there then update your WordPress core files only.

Comment: 1.Nothing in console, the page is loading perfectly as if no password was required at all. 

 2. I have tried switching to the default twentyfifteen wordpress theme. Page still loads as if no password is required. 

 2. I also tried deactivating all the plugins, to no avail. 

 3. I've managed to password-protect individual posts but I'm not sure that's a sustainable solution - I'd rather just password-protect the page the posts appear on. 

 4. I've used PHP for a fair bit before so I can change it if necessary, but this is my first time with wordpress as you can tell :(

Comment: ....Also my first time posting in stackoverflow, I still haven't gotten the hang of this >_>

Comment: Update all word press core files except wp-content directory through FTP.

Comment: It's locally hosted, so nothing to update via FTP. It doesn't even work locally =/

Comment: I've got the latest stable wordpress install already, and all my plugins are up to date. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your admin post page when you have submitted the page and got a success message about password implemented. Also take a screenshot of console at the same time.

Comment: I think the solution is good really good. If its not working for you then must doubt on your core WordPress files or the process you are following. I hope the screenshots will explain your issue.

Comment: Coming back to this now, it seems that a page of posts is considered an archive page and as such can't be password protected. I asked the same question in wordpress.stackoverflow.com and got this:

When you create a page and assign it to "Page for post" in Settings->Reading, it is not considered a page anymore but an archive. Taht is why standard password protection doesn't work. You will need to build the latest posts page at your own, for example using a page template and/or pre_get_posts action.